# Visual Studio Code wont run code and gives no error message

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So when running any code, no matter the language visual studio ignores the code and just doesn't run. all i see is it skips to the next line in the terminal and gives no output. Not even something like hello world runs. It gives no error message whatsoever, just doesn't run.

Comment: Let's concentrate on a specific language/example so you can provide a more detailed question. Since you tagged Python, can you confirm that the Python extension is installed and provide a small 'hello world' code? Also, how do you launch the program (Keyboard shortcut or command)?

Comment: I'm using Python. i wrote hello world like i normally would. print("Hello World!") . I have had the Python extension installed and am using an extension called Code Runner to run with code with Ctrl + Shift + N. The Code runs perfectly in the IDE that comes with Python. It's with any code whatsoever.

Comment: What if you go in the Debug window (Ctrl+Shift+D) and press the arrow icon (or simply press F5). If this is your first using this button for this project, you will have to specify that you want to launch the current file.

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much

Comment: My pleasure. However, it does not explain why Code Runner doesn't launch the script properly. Doing a quick search, it seems that some people had similar problems. If you want to continue using Code Runner, I suggest to look for other questions, and if you cannot find a proper solution, ask another question which contains your specific case.

Comment: If you uninstall Code Runner then the Python extension for VS Code will provide a way to run Python code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, so i switched to Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, instead of Visual Studio Code, and that fixed the issue so now i don't have to worry about extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, running code in any language would cause it not to run, but no error message was produced. I eventually opened up developer tools and saw that no extensions were loading, somewhere the path got corrupt.

I fixed the issue by uninstalling each extension, uninstalling VS Code, deleting the extensions out of the folder they live in, then reinstalling VS Code and the extensions.

After that they ran fine.

While a full reinstall is not ideal, this was the only method I could find to fix it. There is not much info on this issue online, so I'm adding my experience and the fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled mingw and vs code both but nothing happened. Even i uninstalled and reinstalled code runner extension as well.

But what worked for me is going to extensions menu then selecting code runner extension and in extension settings select the checkbox- Run In Terminal.

It should help in case it is not working for code runner extension.